# Nested maps with different structure

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and I want to build an object that looks like below and then convert to Json, but doing something like this gives me error. How can I achieve this?

This is what I tried:

```
Map(a -> Map(b-> "1", c -> "2"),
Map(d -> values.map(v => Map(b-> v.value1, c -> v.value2)))
.asJson
```

Expected outcome:

```
{
"a":{"b": "1", "c": "2"},
"d":[{"b":"x1","c":"x2"},{"b":x3,"c":"x4"}...]
}
```

Comment: In general, you would want to model your data using case class and then convert that to a `Json`, or if this is something used in a single place then you may indeed consider using the `Json` type provided by your library rather than using an heterogeneous map.

Comment: you are right @AndriyPlokhotnyuk Updated

Comment: It is used in just one place. What do you mean by "your library" @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez? can you provide any example?

Comment: You are using some kind of library to manage JSON, be it **circe**, **uPickle**, **zio-json**, etc. Each one of those would have a proper way to build a `Json` object, just like the accepted answer shows how to do it using **circe**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reserve to using the JSON library's provided DSL instead, i.e. circe JSON DSL:

```
import io.circe.Json
import io.circe.syntax.*

Json.obj(
  "a" := Json.obj("b" := "1", "c" := "2")
  "d" := values.map(v => Json.obj("b" := v.value1, "c" := v.value2))
)
```